# "Variable to be used not initialized" warning

Tags: c, gcc, initialization, warnings

This code I'm testing gives me a list of files that are in the current working directory.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main (void)
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *ep;
    dp = opendir ("./");
    if (dp != NULL)
    {
        while (ep == readdir (dp))
        {
            puts (ep->d_name);
            (void) closedir (dp);
        }
    }
    else
        puts ("Couldn't open the directory.");
    return 0;
}
```

The code works, but the compilation with GCC gives me a warning telling me (I use GCC in Spanish) **that can happen that the variable `ep` may be used without initializing in the function**.

I've trying to give the variable `ep` a valor to avoid this warning (good practice of programming), but to do it results the program not doing what it's supposed to do.

Any idea what's going on, or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are equating an uninitialized variable `ep` to return value of a function in this line

```
while (ep == readdir(dp))
```

You want assignment

```
while ((ep = readdir(dp)))
```

If you want to read all the entries you may want to move `closedir()` outside the `while` loop

```
closedir(dp); //no need to cast
```

Comment: It gives me another warning suggesting me use of parentheses around the assignation used as a true valor, just in the line you suggested this change.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to write

```
while ((ep = readdir(dp)))
```

because writing `==` would not assign anything to ep.

The test for the while condition will happen on the result of the expression `ep = readdir(dp)`, evaluated to ep final value.

Comment: Use a pair of parenthesis around the assignment to avoid yet another warning.

Answer (score 1):

```
  puts (ep->d_name); //you are tried access uninitialized pointer
```

Actually you need to read directory using `readdir` , `readdir` returns `struct dirent *` 
Now store this return value into ep and need to check `readdir` is success or failed.

`If an error occurs, NULL is returned and errno is set appropriately.`

you need to check ep is NULL or not , but you are check `ep == readdir(dp)`

```
  while (ep == readdir (dp)) ==> while (ep = readdir (dp))  
            ^^                             ^
```

For clear understanding you can write

```
     while ( (ep == readdir (dp))  !=NULL)
```